# $\lim_{n \to \infty}[n,+\infty)$ has Lebesgue measure 0?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm trying to show that $\lim_{n \to \infty}[n,+\infty)$ has Lebesgue measure 0. I'm so tempted to just state that as $n \to \infty$, the interval gets smaller and smaller and eventually to 0 but I know for sure that is not a legal move. Any hint is appreciated!

Comment: This is a peculiar notation; what does $\lim_{n\to\infty} A_n$ mean where  $A_n$ are subsets of $\Bbb R$?

Comment: You have to be a little more careful about what that limit means.  At first blush, I would say that $\lim_{n\to\infty} [n,\infty) = \emptyset$, as if $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then there is an $N$ so large that $x < n$ for all $n \ge N$.  Thus $x \not\in [n,\infty)$ for $n > N$.  Therefore $x$ isn't an element of the limiting set.  But this assumes that the limit is some kind of intersection of sets.  There are other possible ways of thinking of this limit.

Comment: I'm sorry for not specifying the space. It is $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @YaG The concern is not about what space you are working in---that was fairly clear from context.  The question is about what the limit means.  What do you mean by $\lim_{n\to\infty} [n,\infty)$?  I know what a limit of a sequence of numbers is, and I know many different notions of a limit of sequences of functions, but I'm not entirely sure that I have ever seen a limit of a sequence of sets.  How are you taking that limit?  What does the notation mean?

Comment: @XanderHenderson I don't quite understand. My guess is also $\lim_{n\to\infty}[n,\infty)=\phi$ but I don't understand where you said $n$ is so large that any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ wouldn't be in the set. And I don't see how that can be relevant to showing the limit is empty.

Comment: @XanderHenderson perhaps it's better to view the limit as $\cap_n [n,\infty)$?

Comment: @XanderHenderson I'm just thinking of this interval as a decreasing sequence of sets where $A_{n}\supseteq A_{n+1}$ for all $n$.

Comment: @welshman500 I guess you are right. I was thinking of the problem like that but wasn't quite paying too much attention to the notation.

Comment: @welshman500 My first comment views the limit as an intersection, just as you suggest.  But one could also think of it as a limit of characteristic functions and ask about convergence in measure, or in $L^1$ (hint:  it doesn't), or pointwise, or whatever.  The point is that $\lim_{n\to\infty} A_n$ is not really well-defined notation.

Comment: $\bigcap_n [n,\infty)$ is indeed equal to the empty set, which has measure zero. On the other hand, this is a prominent counterexample to a "continuity of measure" result $\mu(\bigcap_n A_n) = \lim_n \mu(A_n)$ which is true for a decreasing sequence of sets with *finite* measure.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Intuitively, I can also see that it is an empty set. But what is the reasoning behind it?

Comment: @YaG let $x\in \mathbb R.$ Then there is a natural number $k>x.$ $x\notin [k,\infty),$ so by the definition of intersection $x\notin \cap_n [n,\infty).$ Thus no $x$ is in $\cap_n [n,\infty),$ so $\cap_n [n,\infty) = \emptyset.$

Comment: I've seen the notation $\liminf A_n = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \bigcap_{m=n}^\infty A_m$ and $\limsup A_n = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{m=n}^\infty A_m$.  With that, wouldn't it make sense to say $\lim_{n\to \infty} A_n = A$ if $\limsup A_n = \liminf A_n = A$?  (As happens in this case, and I think it would be equivalent to pointwise convergence of indicator functions.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, the notation $\lim_{n\to\infty} A_n$ where $A_n$ are subsets of a larger space is not really well-defined.  What is the limiting procedure?  How do you compute such a limit?  In high-faluten language, in what category are you taking the limit?

That being said, a the usual interpretation is as follows: we first define the "limit superior" and "limit inferior" of a sequence of sets.  These are
$$
\limsup A_n := \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty} A_k
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\liminf A_n := \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty} A_k.
$$
Basically, the limit superior is the collection of point that appear in infinitely many of the sets, and the limit inferior is the set of points that appear in all but finitely many of the sets.  If
$$ \limsup A_n = \liminf A_n = A, $$
then it is reasonable to define $\lim_{n\to\infty} A_n = A$.  In the case where $A_n = [n,\infty)$, the $A_n$ are a monotonically decreasing family of sets (that is, $A_{n+1} \subseteq A_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$), and so these definitions reduce to an intersection:
$$ \limsup [n,\infty)
= \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty} [k,\infty)
= \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} [n,\infty)
= \emptyset $$
and
$$ \liminf [n,\infty)
= \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty} [k,\infty)
= \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \emptyset
= \emptyset. $$
To see that the intersection really is empty, it is sufficient to show that if $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then $x \not\in \bigcap [n,\infty)$.  For this, it is sufficient to show that $x \not\in [n,\infty)$ for at least one $n$.  But this is straightforward:  if $n$ is an integer with $n > x$, then $x \not\in [n,\infty)$.  Since we can always find an integer bigger than $x$, it must be that $x\not\in \bigcap [n,\infty)$.  Therefore if $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then
$$ x\not\in \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} [n,\infty). $$
Then, as claimed, $\bigcap [n,\infty) = \emptyset$, from which it follows that it has zero Lebesgue measure.

Comment: For a sequence of sets $A_n$, you can always define the $\limsup$ and $\liminf$. The $\limsup$ is the set of points which fall in infinitely many of $A_n$ and the $\liminf$ is the set of points which fall in all but finitely many of $A_n$. We always have $\liminf A_n \subseteq \limsup A_n$ and we typically only define $\lim A_n$ when the two are equal and in that case define the limit to be this mutual set. In this case, we do indeed have $\liminf A_n = \limsup A_n = \varnothing$ and so we do have $\lim A_n = \varnothing$.